# Java Regex only start of string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a huge string which I would like to match to the following regex:

```
"\\s*<?.*?>\\s*<abc>[\\s\\S]*|\\s*<abc>[\\s\\S]*"
```

as in

```
myHugeString.matches("\\s*<?.*?>\\s*<abc>[\\s\\S]*|\\s*<abc>[\\s\\S]*"));
```

The string is enormous, so matching the [\s\S]* at the end is taking up a huge amount of time. I am looking to only match the first portion `(\\s*<?.*?>\\s*<abc>)`, and I don't care about anything after that.

What would be the most efficient way of going about this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Pattern* and *Matcher* classes here:

- Create a [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) object by compiling the regex using [`Pattern#compile(regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String%29).
- Then create a [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) object by applying that `Pattern` object on your string using [`Pattern#matcher(CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matcher%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).
- And then use [`Matcher#find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) method to find the pattern you are interested in.

Sample Code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*<?.*?>\\s*<abc>|\\s*<abc>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourString);

if (matcher.find()) {
    // Pattern found.
}
```

You can even shorten your regex pattern to:

```
"(?:\\s*<?.*?>)?\\s*<abc>"
```